# Java Preferences JTextField and JPasswordField issue?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, preferences, jpasswordfield

In my code, I try to set `Preferences`. I have two input fields: `JTextField` and `JPasswordField`. `JPasswordField` works fine, however `JTextField` does not keep in memory the preference info, instead it copies the password info.

```
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;
import javax.swing.*;


public class TestJP {

    public static Preferences userPreferences = Preferences.userRoot();
    public final static String LOGIN_KEY = "";
    public final static String PASSWORD_KEY = "";


    public static void main(String[] args) {


              JTextField login = new JTextField(20);
              login.setText(userPreferences.get(LOGIN_KEY, ""));
              JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField(20);
              password.setText(userPreferences.get(PASSWORD_KEY, ""));

              JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
              myPanel.add(new JLabel("login:"));
              myPanel.add(login);
              myPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15)); 
              myPanel.add(new JLabel("password:"));
              myPanel.add(password);

              int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel, 
                       "Please Login", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
              if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {

                 userPreferences.put(LOGIN_KEY,login.getText());
                 userPreferences.put(PASSWORD_KEY, password.getText());

              }

           }

    }
```

Does `JPasswordField` override somehow the `JTextField`?

Comment: not caused, please whats real issue, to try to switch (LOGIN_KEY), "" with ("", LOGIN_KEY), better (LOGIN_KEY, LOGIN_KEY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your keys are BOTH empty strings. They need to be unique strings.

Before:

```
public final static String LOGIN_KEY = "";
public final static String PASSWORD_KEY = "";
```

New:

```
public final static String LOGIN_KEY = "login_key";
public final static String PASSWORD_KEY = "password_key";
```

Comment: Thank You! It works perferct! But I am still confused, how come it worked for the `JPasswordField` even though it was an empty string?Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! Look at the order in which you are saving the preferences. Password was saved last, thus overwriting your previously saved login pref. The empty string you were using as a key, was still technically a valid key. A key which was being used for both the login and password stored pref.